# How to remove the environment variables from Laravel Debug?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to remove the environment variables, database details and the information showing on Laravel Debug.

Comment: If this is a production site you should have `APP_DEBUG=false` in your env. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors

Comment: If I make app debug false then I will not see the error pages like these. But I need the error page without the environment and details.

Comment: there is an ads in this question

Comment: Note that disabling debug mode does not secure you from your server credentials ending up in webpages/api responses. There have been plenty of cases in the past where the Whoops page was rendered while APP_DEBUG=FALSE. If you want to be absolutely certain that your server credentials don't end up on the internet either: 1) Don't install devdependencies `composer install --no-dev` or 2) Don't use Laravel

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to config/app and add the following

```
 /**
 * Debug Blacklist
 */
'debug_blacklist' => [
    '_COOKIE' => array_keys($_COOKIE),
    '_SERVER' => array_keys($_SERVER),
    '_ENV' => array_keys($_ENV),        
],
```

it will replace all environment variables value with an asterisks (*******)

Answer (score 4):

This is from my config/app file:

```
'debug_blacklist' => [
        '_ENV' => [
            'APP_KEY',
            'DB_DATABASE',
            'DB_PASSWORD',
            'DB_USERNAME',
            'REDIS_PASSWORD',
            'MAIL_PASSWORD',
            'PUSHER_APP_KEY',
            'PUSHER_APP_SECRET',
        ],
        '_SERVER' => [
            'APP_KEY',
            'DB_DATABASE',
            'DB_PASSWORD',
            'DB_USERNAME',
            'REDIS_PASSWORD',
            'MAIL_PASSWORD',
            'PUSHER_APP_KEY',
            'PUSHER_APP_SECRET',
        ],
        '_POST' => [
            'password',
        ],
    ],
```

Add this array to our config/app file, the the system will replace real values with ***.

[image]

This way is useful if you want control on specific key items.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own error pages. ([official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#custom-http-error-pages))

Make a blade file for 500 errors. (resources/views/errors/500.blade.php)

And print error messages or trace log

```
<h2>{{ $exception->getMessage() }}</h2>
```

Answer (score -2):

Change from APP_DEBUG=true to APP_DEBUG=false in the .env file. Then you can rely on the laravel logs for your errors. (yourLarvelApp/storage/logs)

Answer (score -2):

Go to your project file: open .env file in notepad and find out **APP_DEBUGAPP_DEBUG=true**   you just rename **false**; and save. your problem is solve.